# como editar un registro en asp.net mvc con una llave primaria compuesta por tres campos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc5

tengo un sistema con una base de datos con una llave primaria compuesta por 3 campos,
año, mes y id_empleado, la ultima es la llave primaria de otra tabla (tabla empleado),

les muestro mi controlador y la vista:

Controlador metodo editar:

> public ActionResult Edit(int? anio, int? mes, int? id_empleado)
> {
> if (anio == null && mes == null && id_empleado == null)
> {
> return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
> }
> resumen resumen = db.resumen.Find(anio, mes, id_empleado);
> if (resumen == null)
> {
> return HttpNotFound();
> }
> ViewBag.id_empleado = new SelectList(db.empleado, "id_empleado", "nom_empleado", resumen.id_empleado);
>
> ```
>         //ViewBag.mes = new SelectList(db.resumen, "mes", "mes", resumen.id_empleado);
>
>
>         List<SelectListItem> meses = new List<SelectListItem>();
>
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Enero", Value = "1" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Febrero", Value = "2" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Marzo", Value = "3" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Abril", Value = "4" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mayo", Value = "5" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Junio", Value = "6" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Julio", Value = "7" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Agosto", Value = "8" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Septiembre", Value = "9" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Octubre", Value = "10" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Noviembre", Value = "11" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Diciembre", Value = "12" });
>
>         ViewBag.mes = meses;
>
>         return View(resumen);
>     }
>
>     // POST: resumen_control_calidad/Edit/5
>     // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
>     // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
>     [HttpPost]
>     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>     public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "anio,mes,id_empleado,etc")] resumen resumen, int? anio, int? mes,
> ```
>
> int? id_empleado)
> {
>
> ```
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>            
>             db.Entry(resumen).State = EntityState.Modified;
>             db.SaveChanges();
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>
>         ViewBag.id_empleado = new SelectList(db.empleado, "id_empleado", "nom_empleado", resumen.id_empleado);
>
>
>         List<SelectListItem> meses = new List<SelectListItem>();
>
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Enero", Value = "1" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Febrero", Value = "2" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Marzo", Value = "3" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Abril", Value = "4" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mayo", Value = "5" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Junio", Value = "6" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Julio", Value = "7" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Agosto", Value = "8" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Septiembre", Value = "9" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Octubre", Value = "10" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Noviembre", Value = "11" });
>         meses.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Diciembre", Value = "12" });
>
>         ViewBag.mes = meses;
>
>
>
>         return View(resumen);
>     }
> ```

y mi vista editar es la siguiente:

> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.anio)
>             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.mes)
>             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id_empleado)
>
> ```
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <strong>Año</strong>
>
>             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.anio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:270px;"
> ```
>
> } })
> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.anio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>
> ```
>         </div>
>     </div>
>
>
>     <div class="cbp-mc-column2x">
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <strong>Mes</strong>
>
>             @Html.DropDownList("mes", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:270px;" })
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>
>             @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.mes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
>
>         </div>
>
>     </div>
>
>
>
>
>     <div class="cbp-mc-column2x">
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <strong>Empleado</strong>
>
>             @Html.DropDownList("id_empleado", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:270px;"
> ```
>
> })
> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_empleado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>
> ```
>         </div>
>
>     </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

cuando ejecuto la aplicacion, me guarda los registros pero no me modifica ni el año, mes y id_empleado, los demas campos de la tabla si los modifica, pero los tres que componen el ID no, me gustaria saber que mas le falta al metodo editar del controlador para que pueda guardar esos tres campos.